# Get projects to be build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the eclipse toolbar when you mouse over the build button it comes up with a tooltip
saying which projects are currently selected to be build. Is there any way to get that information in my eclipse plugin? I thought about implementing something with ISelectionListener to keep tracking which projects are selected but there is no reason to do that if I can get them from the same place the build button is taking them.

Comment: Your conception of that button showing a project being built is wrong. That button shows a launch configuration, which might be building one project, many projects or doing completely different things (like launching tests, running a Maven execution or whatever).

So what _problem_ do you really want to solve? That button approach is a _solution_ description and probably not a good one.

Comment: What I wanted is just to track which projects are being selected the same way that build button is doing. I do not care what the that button is using the selected projects for. I just want the selection mechanism to get them and I thought that maybe was a shortcut getting that info from that button instead of implementing an ISelectionListener with the same functionality. Finally I end up creating that ISelectionListener as I could not figure out how to extract that info from that button.

Comment: I suggest you give your own comment also as the answer, as that selection listener _is_ the best solution. :)

Comment: Thanks! I just post the implementation as an answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer to this question was to create my own ISelectionListener.

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
    Object[] allselections= null;
    selectedProjects.clear();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        allselections = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).toArray();
        for(Object element: allselections){

            if (element instanceof IResource) {
                selectedProjects.add(((IResource)element).getProject());
            } else if (element instanceof IAdaptable) {
                IResource resource = null;
                IAdaptable a = (IAdaptable)element;
                resource = (IResource)a.getAdapter(IResource.class);
                selectedProjects.add(resource.getProject());

            }
        }
    }
};
```